# Change the local links to production links while grunt build?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

Can we change the links in grunt which mostly will be local to production links during grunt build?

For e.g.

```
.a-container {
    background: url(../images/hello.jpg) no-repeat top center;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

After build it should look like

```
.a-container {
    background: url(http://hello.com/blah/blah/hello.jpg) no-repeat top center;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

We have the URL upfront which can be configured in grunt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete the question which I started off, here how you can achieve it.

```
        compass: {
              dist: {
               options: {
                 config: 'app/config.rb',
                 sassDir: 'app/styles',
                 cssDir: 'dist/styles',
                 imagesDir: 'app/images/',
                 javascriptsDir: 'app/scripts',
                 fontsDir: 'app/styles/fonts',
                 importPath: 'app/components',
                 outputStyle: 'compressed',
            },
        },
     }
```

And you should have a config.rb file as Compass doesn't expose some options as command line arguments.

```
config.rb

http_images_path = "http://cdn.example.com/images/"
```

Also in your sass/scss files don't forget to use, `image_url('hello.jpg')` instead of only `url('hello.jpg')` , url() is ignored by Compass.

Next time when you run `grunt compass:dist` you will have the urls baked into the generated css files.

Comment: What options do you need in compass that aren't available in grunt-contrib-compass? The one you specified is here: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass#httpimagespath

Comment: Yup that's true but it doesn't work as expected and you get an error saying , "Error: invalid option: --http-images-path" .. here is the issue and the fix as well, https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass/issues/13

Comment: Ah cool, good to know. Glad this solution worked for you. I <3 grunt-contrib-compass

Answer (score 1):

If you're not stuck using raw CSS, I'd recommend throwing [grunt-contrib-compass](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass) on top of the project. You'll be able to set dev/production environments and run them when you want. You'll specifically want to look at the [option for images](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass#imagesdir). I structure mine in the following way:

```
compass: {
  dev: {
    sassDir: 'build/sass',
    cssDir: 'stylesheets',
    imagesDir: 'build/assets/images/'
  },
  production: {
    sassDir: 'build/sass',
    cssDir: 'stylesheets',
    imagesDir: 'http://example.com/images'
  },
}
```

You don't have to necessarily leverage other parts of sass/comapss (though there will be some upfront work switching the directory and file structure around).

If this approach doesn't work for you, you may want to take a look at Yeomans [usemin task](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin). Unfortunately, I'm not *as* familiar with that one and can't provide much help with it.